# boost library name without tag in mingw

Tags: c++, boost

I compile boost library in mingw in windows, and I want my library name without tag.
For example, boost python is just libboost_python, not libboost_python-mgw48-mt-1_54.dll.
I find out one of the answer in http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/builtins/features.html. It said that

```
tag

The tag feature is used to customize the name of the generated files. The value should have the form:

@rulename

where rulename should be a name of a rule with the following signature:

rule tag ( name : type ? : property-set )
```

But I do not know how to use such information.

Here is my compile command

b2 toolset=gcc variant=release link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared --with-python

to get libboost_python-mgw48-mt-1_54.dll. so I guess to use

b2 toolset=gcc variant=release link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared tag=@ rule tag ( name : type ) --with-python

to get libboost_python.dll, but it does not work

Comment: add `--layout=system` option to `b2` line.